# JavaScript IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer

My site Menus stopped working in IE 11 I am still learning but I need help to fix this issue. I am posting what I think the issue is. I don't understand the primary_nav. this was all built by a person before me. I keep reading how this (getElementsByClassName) is no longer good since IE 8 but has been working til now.

```
Navigation.prototype = {
initialize : function () {
    this.bound_show_menu = this.show_menu.bindAsEventListener(this);
    this.bound_hide_menu = this.hide_menu.bindAsEventListener(this);

    var drop_menus = document.getElementsByClassName('primary_nav')[0].getElementsByClassName('drop');

    for (i=0; i<drop_menus.length; i++) {
        Element.extend(drop_menus[i]);
        Event.observe(drop_menus[i], 'mouseover', this.show_menu);
        Event.observe(drop_menus[i], 'mouseout', this.hide_menu);
    }
},

show_menu : function (event) {

    var elt = Event.element(event);
    if (elt.hasClassName('drop')) {
        elt.addClassName('over');
    } else {
        elt.up('.drop').addClassName('over');
    }

},

hide_menu : function (event) {

    var elt = Event.element(event);
    if (elt.hasClassName('drop')) {
        elt.removeClassName('over');
    } else {
        elt.up('.drop').removeClassName('over');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` should be fine in modern browsers, including IE9 and up. IE8 and lower do not support it.

Are you seeing any errors in IE11's developer console? Do you have any dependencies (e.g. Prototype or jQuery?) Can you put together a JSFiddle or similar to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Yes I am getting errors on the F12 menu that hits the primary_nav line and the error is "Unable to get property 'getElementsByClass Name' of undefined or null reference" Dependencies not sure I don't think so. The problem is at jprofleetproducts.com and the menu do not drop down in IE 11. I will try this JSFiddle.

Comment: You're getting that error in other browsers, too. `document.getElementsByClassName('primary_nav')` isn't returning anything because there's nothing in the document where `class="primary_nav"`. There's also an error in `accordion.pack.js`. Also you have a dependency on [Prototype 1.6.0](http://prototypejs.org/).

Comment: Also, I don't think this is the script that's controlling the menus at all. It's `http://jprofleetproducts.com/includes/transmenu.js`. Can you run `TransMenu.isSupported()` in the F12 console and see what comes back? If it's false, it's due to TransMenu's outdated browser detection code.

Comment: I get back a True in the console.

Comment: Interesting... Can you try using the latest version of the script anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with outdated browser detection code in your version of the TransMenus script.

In fact it looks like Aaron Boodman fixed this issue a couple of years ago (by removing that bit of code entirely). Grab the latest versions of the CSS and JS from https://github.com/aboodman/transmenus/ and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I found that javascript was not working at all on IE 11. After researching I found that there is a patch for it http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939. I am running Server 2003 SP2, IIS6. It seems IIS or ASP was not recognizing IE11 as a browser that supported Javascript. The patch worked for me.

I now have an problem where ReportViewer is not working with IE11, but that's another issue.